# How to calculate correlation coefficient and P-value between three dimensional matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, correlation

I have two gridded matrix having latitude,longitude and time(180x360x12). I have calculated correlation coefficient between both matrices using following: http://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/15884-correlation-for-multi-dimensional-arrays

now I want to find p-value (0.05) for each grid cell. than I want to set correlation values in matrix in three part: one will show positively significant (<0.05), second will show positively insignificant (>0.05) and third will show negatively significant (<0.05) correlation. Can anyone help me in this regard ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the scipy [pearsonr](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html#scipy.stats.pearsonr) function to calculate your correlations then this will give you the p values as well.

If `cor` are the correlations and `p` are the p-values then retrieving the significant values is then as simple as:

```
significant_correlations = corr[p<0.05]
```